# Power supply issues - reboots continuously but GPIO power working

Tags: gpio, usb, power

My Raspberry Pi 2 was working with OpenELEC os properly.
Suddenly it had stopped working. I don't know whether it had updated anything automatically.
It is continuously rebooting. I could see the startup screen but reboots.
I could see the power LED is toggling during this.

I checked by powering it with GPIO input. It is working but the USB ports are not detecting. Other than USB, Ethernet, HDMI are working fine.

So kindly guide me how I can check this issue.

Is this a hardware issue or the software ?

PS:
Power supply, SD and other things are fine since they are working with my new Raspberry Pi 3 board.

Answer (score 1):

> **Suddenly** it had stopped working

and

> USB ports are not detecting

but

> Power supply, SD and other things are fine

indicates the hardware problem with Pi itself. But I'd still check with

- another power supply and/or cable (it might be the USB socket or cable fault, plug might fit enough to power it up but fail to provide more current)
- another SD card with clean and maybe different system image, just to make sure it isn't software issue

Comment: I think problem is not with these. Because I had checked with another OSMC os with new SD card. Once I powered ON, the installation was happening properly. After the successful installation, it was rebooting. After that the same issue is observed.

Comment: BTW, Hi Mark, thanks for your comments and your time.